# algorithm used on giving answers based on user's data

Tags: algorithm

I just would like to ask is what do you call the algorithm used on giving results based on the data entered by users? somewhat similar to giving suggestions.

Comment: it is hard to understand what you are asking for. can we please have an example?

Comment: You mean something like auto-completion? There can be lots of different algorithms behind it. Basically it is a search with pattern matching and ranking applied.

Comment: I think you are asking for somewhat like  Google search/auto-completion.Every search engine uses its own search algorithm which is kept secret...you can build your own AI/Algorithm for that purpose.